# Define width of a path and calculate area

Tags: r, path, spatial

I used video tracking software to track animals as they moved around in an arena. The data are X,Y coordinates (in pixels) of the animal's position at time Z (in frame number). An example dataframe looks like:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,4,4,4,3,2,1)
y <- c(1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4)
z <- 1:length(x)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
```

I am interested in the animal's behavior and would like to calculate a metric of "area of arena explored." I'm not sure the best way to go about this, but my initial thought is to create a step-wise path from the points, then define a buffer-width to the path to create a polygon, and finally, calculate the area of the plane under the polygon. Visually, I could imagine something like:

```
plot(x, y, type = "o", lwd = 20)
```

[image]

I'm not experienced in spatial data like these, but I 'think' I could rasterize this path? Unfortunately, the `lwd` command is not absolute, so if my plane expands, the line width will not scale with it.

I would prefer to use R rather than GIS software.

I suspect there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in studying animal's path, but I think this is a great idea.

We can use the `sf` package, which is the next generation standard of class and methods to analyze spatial data in R.

To illustrate how it works, let's begin with a simple example. We will draw a line from `c(0, 1)` to `c(1, 1)`. We will then create a buffer with a distance equal to 1. Finally, we will calculate the area of the buffer zone.

```
library(sf)

# Create a simple feature object based on df
ps <- as.matrix(rbind(c(0, 1), c(1, 1)))
ls <- st_linestring(ps)
# View the line
plot(ls)
```

[image]

```
# Create a buffer zone
ls_buffer <- st_buffer(ls, dist = 1)

# View ls_buffer
plot(ls_buffer)
```

[image]

```
# Calculate the area
st_area(ls_buffer)
[1] 5.140157
```

The line and buffer zone looks good. We can also calculate the area using the `st_area` function. The shape of the buffer zone is similar to a rectangle with a width equal to 1 and height equal to 2, plus a circle with radius equal to 1. We can calculate the area using the following code. The result is similar to what we got from the `st_area` function.

```
2 * 1 + 1 * 1 * pi
[1] 5.141593
```

Now, it is easy to modify the above codes for your example. I set the buffer distance to be 0.1, but you will need to determine a reasonable buffer distance.

```
# Create example data frame
x <- c(1,2,3,4,4,4,4,3,2,1)
y <- c(1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4)
z <- 1:length(x)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

# Create a simple feature object based on df
ps <- as.matrix(df[, c("x", "y")])
ls <- st_linestring(ps)
# View the line
plot(ls)
```

[image]

```
# Create a buffer zone
ls_buffer <- st_buffer(ls, dist = 0.1)

# View ls_buffer
plot(ls_buffer)
```

[image]

```
# Calculate the area
st_area(ls_buffer)
[1] 2.263725
```

The `sf` package is fairly new, so I am still learning it and there are probably a lot of functionalities that I don't know yet. Please visit this package website on CRAN (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html) and access those vignettes if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

This approach involves GIS techniques within R but I think it's fairly straightforward and follows the three steps you laid out.

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(dplyr)

#Convert points to path (SpatialLines object)    
SOlines <- Line(coordinates(df[,1:2])) %>% list() %>% Lines(ID="test") %>% list() %>% SpatialLines()
#Buffer the path into a polygon
area <- rgeos::gBuffer(SOlines,width = .1, byid = T) 
#Calculate the area within the Polygon
rgeos::gArea(area,byid=T)
        test 
    2.262897
```

The `sf` package (as in ycw's answer) has a more straightforward way of creating the line path. I'm not so familiar with that package yet but I'll keep this answer up for now as one good thing about using SpatialLines approach is that you can store multiple Lines (IDs) in one object and then calculate all areas in one call of `gArea`.